# React - how to open modal when user tries to reload or close window/tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alert, onbeforeunload

I am trying to trigger a modal when user tries to reload the page, visit new URL or close the browser window/tab.

At the moment, the code is successfully triggering the modal, but a default alert window also pops up which I want to get rid of:

[image: Modal appears below the default alert window (using FireFox)]

*Modal appears below the default alert window (using FireFox)*

Code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnload)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.onUnload)
  }

  onUnload(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more recommended way to accomplish this, but overriding the `alert` function should work:

```
onUnload(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const nativeAlert = window.alert
    window.alert = console.log // Temporarily override the alert function
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true })
    window.alert = nativeAlert // Restore it to default
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but seems like the default alert prompt is still showing up

Comment: For me, it doesn't show default alert, but page still reloads.